# Select all records where open code, but no close with date later than open?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have a table that contains the data as below

> ```
> AccountNo Code    Date
> 123456    OpenCS  01/12/2013
> 123456    CloseCS 03/12/2013
> 123456    CALLIN  11/10/2013
> 123456    CloseCS 08/08/2009
> 111587    OpenCS  12/12/2013
> 111587    CloseCS 01/12/2013
> ```

What I need to get is all Accounts with a completed OpenCS code but no CloseCS AFTER the OpenCS

So I have 2 selects querys

```
Select AccountNo, Code, Date FROM tblTrans
WHERE Code = ‘OpenCS’
```

AND

```
Select AccountNo, Code, Date FROM tblTrans
WHERE Code = ‘CloseCS’
```

Where im falling down is joining these to get the required data. Tried a couple of joins but cant get the select to exclude the records.

So with this it would only return account 111587 as the Close was done before the Open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tblTrans t
WHERE Code = 'OpenCS' 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM tblTrans t2
   WHERE t2.AccountNo = t.AccountNo
   AND   t2.Date > t.Date
   AND   t2.Code = 'CloseCS'
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3a73/1/0)</kbd>

```
ACCOUNTNO   CODE    DATE
111587     OpenCS   December, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Worth reading in this context: [should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) (conclusion: NOT EXISTS is typically going to be your best choice)

Comment: @dav1dsm1th: Thanks, but why have you posted this link? It's a matter of preference if you use `NULL` or `1` or `*` or whatever in the `EXISTS` since nothing is selected anyway. I prefer `1` since it's short and readable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `*` and `1` are the same length and are equally readable - but one doesn't perpetuate the myth that there is an effect on performance by choosing one over the other (which is my preference).

Comment: @dav1dsm1th: for this reason i have earlier used `NULL` because it makes it even more clar that it's irrelevant what it selects, meanwhile i don't like `NULL` anymore since i'm lazy. `SELECT 1` makes it clearer than `SELECT *` that the query returns nothing (imho).

Comment: hence my addition on the link - so that people can make up their mind which coding standard to adopt - one that they will see in every code example from Microsoft - or one that has an arbitrary/random constant that has no impact on performance but which gives the impression that it might.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.AccountNo 
FROM tblTrans T1
INNER JOIN tblTrans T2 ON T1.AccountNo = T2.AccountNo
WHERE T1.Code = 'OpenCS' AND T2.Code = 'CloseCS' AND T2.Date < T1.Date
```